# Is there a way to have multiple custom html Forms in a Google Sheets project?

Tags: forms, google-sheets

I have created a second html form and include javascript that contains a "doget" function for the new page and now, neither form works. It seems I would need to generate two urls to show the pages
Code.gs:

```
    function doGet(request){
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
    }
```

ShopCode.gs:

```
    function doGet(request){
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('WebApp').evaluate();
    }
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask